# Can I force the DD port in the TI ISOUSB111 Isolator to be downstream-facing?

Tags: usb, digital-isolator

I am new to USB comm. protocol.  I am using a TI ISOUSB111 Isolator.  The basic setup seems simple enough but it is not working for me as expected, it does not enable recognition of USB devices. I followed the TI implementation in their datasheet fairly closely.  I connect a device to the isolator board DD port, and connect the board UD port to my computer. When connecting a device to the DD lines the USB goes into some kind of idle state. This happens even though the DD+ line is high; the UD+ line and UD- line are also both high.

SO I tried this... I connected the UD port to the device and the DD port to the computer and it works!  Why only this way? Why wouldn`t the DD port see the connect signal first (from device?) and become the internally set downstream facing side? This status should then be transferred via the UD side to the host to enable enumeration.
Thanks-
Tom

The basic circuit:
[image]

Comment: How are your bringing power over?

Comment: I have tried a couple methods for powering the Isolator... a separate 5v USB power supply, and the power supplied by the computer using jumpers- this one negates the isolation of course but I first need to resolve the enumeration issue. The power source seems to make no difference.